# Basic Statistical Tests in a Descriptive Research

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have very limited knowledge on statistical method. Apologies if what I ask for does not make any sense.

I constructed a large dataset from a sample. This sample is selected using a stratified purposive sampling. In the first step, I selected 42 groups based on 13 categories. I selected more than one group for each category to have a variety within each group (maximum variation sampling) but I have no prior data on the number of variations . Then from these groups, I sampled, based on availability, around 2000 households.

The research is descriptive. All I want to show is the range of differences, similarities, and the patterns.

What are the basic statistical tests I need to provide for such design? For instance, do I have to provide sampling error? If so, how do I provide it? Do I estimate it for the 13 categories I know?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!